# Make information on own login history and other sessions visible to user

Tags: feature-request, login, user-accounts, security

I think that a really important security feature, which SE lacks, is that there is no login history. Well, at least, it is not displayed to normal users about their accounts and only to moderators.

I would expect a login history to show the past 10 logins, and of those logins it should show the IP address, the device type, the browser, and the login type (OpenID (which one so they could know where they had been hacked if that was the case) or other login). It should also show you if you are logged in anywhere else, and if you are, it should allow you to log out of that session (all of the same information would be displayed for the 'other sessions section' as would be for the login history).

These features are available on most major sites, so I think that this should also be available on this one for the safety and security of users.

Comment: Area 51 does this. AREA 51 IS USEFUL FOR SOMETHING  (Image link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrs14.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you're looking for https://openid.stackexchange.com - just log in there and get all the login/auth entries with ip and date.

Approximate look of the table:

[image]

Comment: LOL. I'm still logged in since Jul 19 '14 at 15:36. Same lappy. Different IP.